# Javascript loads in application.js file, but doesn't work in Rails 3.2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I hate to even ask this because I'm sure it's something obvious, but I've spent hours searching for an answer and can't find one.

I've got a simple javascript (jquery) code that uses the 'slideup' function. I'm using it on my form partial to show or hide a field based on a selection. If I put the code directly into the form, it works perfectly. If I put it into the assets/javascript folder, it gets included in the application.js file, but doesn't work.

For testing, I also put in an javascript alert just to see if it was loading and it is, the alert fires. I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Here's the javascript located in my app/assets/javascript/form.js:

```
$('#Postponement').change(function () {
    if ($("#NewWeddingDate").is(":hidden")) {
      $("#NewWeddingDate").show("slow");
    } else {
      $("#NewWeddingDate").slideUp();
    }
  })


$(function(){
  alert('got to application.js!');
})
```

And this is the relevant form code (I'm using Formtastic):

```
<div id='Postponement' >

    <%= f.input :Postponement, :label => "Will the wedding be postponed?", :input_html => { :id => 'Postponement' }, :as => :select, :include_blank => false, :collection => ['Yes', 'No'], :selected => 'Yes' %> <br />

    </div>

    <div id = 'NewWeddingDate' >

    <%= f.input :NewWeddingDate, :label => "The new wedding date is:", :input_html => { :id => 'NewWeddingDate' }, :as => :date_select, :start_month => Time.now.month, :start_year => Time.now.year, :end_year => Time.now.year + 10, :order => [:month, :year] %><br />

    </div>
```

My application.html.erb contains the `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` and if I add that javascript code directly into the _form.html.erb file, it works fine.  I'm definitely a newbie at this stuff, so I'm sure it's something obvious. I could get by with just leaving the code in the _form.html.erb, but I'm trying to do things the right (Rails) way. Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making your code run after the document is loaded. Right now, it's probably executing immediately before #Postponement even exists except when you're placing it in the form partial. For example:

```
$(function() {
    $('#Postponement').change(function () {
        if ($("#NewWeddingDate").is(":hidden")) {
          $("#NewWeddingDate").show("slow");
        } else {
          $("#NewWeddingDate").slideUp();
        }
    })
});
```

Placing your function inside the `$()` ensures it runs [after the DOM is fully ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: That was exactly it! Thank you so much.

So, moving forward, do I need to wrap all of my javascript in functions like that to ensure they get loaded last? I was under the impression that with the asset pipeline, the application.js would load first to avoid this exact type of problem.

Thanks again.